# In page addthis share links within a blog feed

Tags: share, addthis, business-catalyst

I'm wondering if anyone could advise. I've already implemented addthis share links into the pages on my website and its working great.

However I am currently building a blog page for the site where I want to include a share link on the list item, I've tried inserting the code, but when you want to share it its pulling in the page title rather the blog title.

I'm using Business Catalyst to create my site, and here is the code that I'm currently using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-54cb9dd9530360bc" async="async"></script>
```

The page in question is http://www.g7g20.com/live

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to change the share title or URL, you can do so by adding the data-url and data-title attributes to the div. For example:

```
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox" data-url="http://www.example.com/blog-post-you-want-to-share" data-title="My blog post title"></div>
```

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/125634-setting-the-url-title-to-share

Comment: Okay, I've given it a go, but still struggling to pull in the title of the individual post, {tag_blog headline} I've inserted it in but it just displays the tag name rather then the content.

Comment: You'll need to use [the correct tag (`tag_blogposttitle_nolink`)](http://docs.businesscatalyst.com/dev-assets/reference#!/tag-reference/blogs/blog-post-details-layout.html), and the `div.addthis_sharing_toolbox` will need to be within the blog module templates for that information to be available in its context.